# Java throw keyword

Tags: java, exception

```
public class MyThrow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(2/0);
        throw new ArithmeticException("please be carefull");
    }
}
```

Why is the custom exception not showing?
It is showing the default one.

Comment: Because an exception is thrown on the previous line, because `2/0` results in an `ArithmeticException`.

Answer (score 1):

For Exception handling we would use a try catch statement like

```
try {
    System.out.println(2/0);
}catch(ArithmeticException e) {
    System.out.println("Please Be Careful");
}
```

In your case the Custom Exception is not showing up since in the previous line you have a AthmeticExcpetion hence that exception will be thrown and Java will stop and not execute you exception.

Comment: I know this way of handling exception but what to know about throw keyword as throw keyword manually send exception object to jvm

Comment: the ```throw``` keyword does throw the expection up a level, for example, if I call a handled method called ```divideByZero(int a, int b)```, I can "catch" the ```ArithmeticException``` and if I wanted the upper functions above to know that an error has occured within a particular method I can "throw" the exception up a level, but be sure to handle the excpetions at the "upper level" too!